# Flashdrive Compatiable for BADUSB use

Tags: memory, hard-disk, memory-card, flash-drive

What is the best and cheapest flash drive that's most likely going to work to turn into a "BadUSB" BADUSB

I believe the controller must be Phison but I can't find anything for under 40$

My issue is I can't find any Flash Drive that's compatible to have the firmware changed. I found a couple but there +80$ . Do they have to be Phison or is there another flash drive compatible.

There is some confusion with a possible duplicate of my other question, I had to repost it because of it being on hold, I had edited it (Which should have taken it off "on-hold" but was never touched. It is There-for able to be reposted as it is no longer active.